# Use interface as type of field in mongoose Schema

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm using typescript and mongoose. I have that interface:

```
interface Job {
  jobid: Boolean;
  title: Boolean; 
}
```

And I want to create a schema where one of the fields is an array of Jobs:

```
const workerSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String required: true }
  first_name: { type: String }
  jobs: [Job]
})
```

But I get error 'Job' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From [Mongoose official documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html):

> Mongoose supports arrays of SchemaTypes and arrays of subdocuments. Arrays of SchemaTypes are also called primitive arrays, and arrays of subdocuments are also called document arrays

If you want your workerSchema to define a jobs property that implements your Job interface, you should do as following:

```
interface Job {
    jobid: Boolean;
    title: Boolean;
  }

const JobSchema = new Schema<Job>({
  jobid: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const workerSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true },
  first_name: { type: String },
  jobs: [JobSchema]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const workerSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String required: true }
  first_name: { type: String }
  jobs: {type:[Job]}
})
```

if no work use a class instead of an interface

Comment: This throws the error: "Job" refers to a type, but is being used as a value instead (2693)